# Could a perfect vacuum exist at the boundary of the universe?

Tags: spacetime, vacuum, dark-energy

Space is not truly a vacuum because of our observation of quantum foam, but if causality does not exist outside our universe, could that mean that quantum foam cannot exist outside our observable universe as well, allowing for a perfect vacuum to exist in all directions causing space-time to expand?

Comment: By definition there is nothing outside of "the universe".

Comment: not sure that there is an edge. Universe may be close like i.e. a sphere surface

Comment: "observation of quantum foam"? Really?

Comment: @thokiro to notice or percieve something and register it as being significant.

Comment: Why do you think that causality does not exist outside our universe?